# NSWindow hides when title bar is unchecked

Tags: macos, nswindow

For some reason when i uncheck the title bar in the attributes inspector of the window. It doesn't show on startup. But when i check it , it shows up.  Anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by subclassing NSWindow and overriding its function

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {

return YES;
```

}